# Visual Studio 2022 + Xamarin iOS App - Unable to launch app on Mac/attached iPhone

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

My environment is as follows:

- Visual Studio 2022 v.17.1.5, running on Windows 11.
- Xcode v.13.3.1, running on macOS Monterey v.12.3.1.
- iPhone 8 connected via USB to Mac.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I created a brand new iOS App (Xamarin) in Visual Studio - I've made no changes to the program code.

[image]

I successfully connected to the Mac from Visual Studio, and selected my iPhone device from the device list:

[image]

But when I then attempt to launch the app, I get the following error in Visual Studio:

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       error MT1001: Could not find an application at the specified directory: /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyXamarinApp.iOS/d2676d815413eba0ea96d8f2e6987c73efb16fc430b9a9f850ef44d200b3818c/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone8.2-14.6/MyXamarinApp.iOS.app          0

The specified folders exist on the Mac up to and including the  "MyXamarinApp.iOS" folder, but the folder is empty.

I've tried reboots on both my Windows PC and the Mac, but same result.

And I've run out of ideas what to try next.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more Googling, it transpires that Resharper's own Build process was interfering with the deployment somehow.  By disabling Resharper completely within Visual Studio, I was able to successfully deploy to my device connected to my Mac.

It was suggested that simply disabling Resharper's Build option should help, but I couldn't get the deployment to work without disabling Resharper completely.

UPDATE: It seems that this is only an issue for new projects for their first build. Once built using Visual Studio’s native build, switching back to Resharper’s build seems to work ok.